# Issue with Shopify Hydrogen Setup in Local Env

Tags: reactjs, remix, shopify-hydrogen

I used the sales Chanel installation and cloned the repo,

after installing all packages using yarn, I keep getting this error when I issue ** yarn dev**

```
StorefrontClient: Using a private storefront token is recommended for server environments. Refer to the authentication https://shopify.dev/api/storefront#authentication documentation for more details.
ReferenceError: URL is not defined.
Attempted to access binding using global in modules.
You must use the 2nd `env` parameter passed to exported handlers/Durable Object constructors, or `context.env` with Pages Functions.
    at EventTarget.get (/Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/node_modules/@miniflare/core/src/standards/event.ts:291:19)
    at handleRequest (/Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/esm/server.js:28:15)
    at /Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/node_modules/@shopify/remix-oxygen/src/server.ts:5:8
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Object.fetch (/Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/server.js:55:24)
    at EventTarget.[kDispatchFetch] (/Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/node_modules/@miniflare/core/src/standards/event.ts:385:13)
    at /Users/fred/Projects/chalestore/node_modules/@shopify/mini-oxygen/dist/mini-oxygen/server.js:114:24
```

Answer (score 1):

Right around then they were having some troubles with the updated @shopify packages and even npm needed some audit fix forces to stand the environment up , but now either yarn or npm should get the project up and moving.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).